# Scipy Objective function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to convert my gurobi code into scipy but I am having trouble defining the objective function. When testing to see if I defined the function correctly I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

The code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
step=80
f1load=[44,48,53,28,32,36,41,48,38,32,38,34,44,36,41,48,38,32,44,48,53,28,32,36,41,48,38,32,38,34,44,36,41,48,38,32,44,48,53,28,32,36,41,48,38,32,38,34,44,36,41,48,38,32,44,48,53,28,32,36,41,48,38,32,38,34,44,36,41,48,38,32,44,48,53,28,32,36,41,48,38,32,38,34,44,36,41,48]
fload=f1load[0:step+1]
i1load=[40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40]
iload=i1load[0:step+1]
#Following command converts fload&iload to arrays and subtracts them from each other 
load1=np.array(iload)-np.array(fload)
load1
#This command converts array to list so we can use it as a list in the rest of the code
load2=load1.tolist()
load=load2
x = np.zeros(80)
x = x.tolist()
def objective(x,load):
# this line is from my gurobi code    obj1=sum(((load[i+1]-(6*x[i]))*(load[i+1]-(6*x[i])) for i in range (n)))
    for i in range(step):
        obj1 = sum((load[i+1]-(6*x[i]))*(load[i+1]-(6*x[i])))
        obj2 = obj2 + obj1
    return obj2

objective(x,load)
```

Full stack trace of error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-cef8470baf0d> in <module>
----> 1 objective(x,load)

<ipython-input-25-a9de3ab9ff2b> in objective(x, load)
      2 #     obj1=sum(((load[i+1]-(6*x[i]))*(load[i+1]-(6*x[i])) for i in range (n)))
      3     for i in range(step):
----> 4         obj1 = sum((load[i+1]-(6*x[i]))*(load[i+1]-(6*x[i])))
      5         obj2 = obj2 + obj1
      6     return obj2

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
obj1 = sum((load[i+1]-(6*x[i]))*(load[i+1]-(6*x[i])))
```

The expression inside the parantheses, `(load[i+1]-(6*x[i]))*(load[i+1]-(6*x[i]))`, evaluates to a `float`, and calling `sum` on that expression gives you the error because the `sum` function expects an iterable argument.